# How does a Unix program like bc cleanly handle input/ouput stream when started as a background job?

Tags: c, unix, io, output, signals

I noticed that the Unix bc program does not print out it's usual prompt (the three symbols ">>> ") when being started as a background process (like if you execute it as "bc &"). This is confusing to me because from my limited knowledge of Unix, starting a program as a background job will keep it running until as soon as it tries to read from stdin, at which point it will receive a signal to stop itself.

But running bc as a background job ("bc &") will not cause it to at least print out the ">>> " prompt before stopping itself which tells me that the program handles that somehow. I am curious as to how it does this. When I wrote a naive program that only tries to emulate the input/output interaction, it still prints out ">>> " before being suspended which doesn't look very clean at all and the behavior gets even more bizarre on certain shells.

I tried looking through the Unix bc source code and I was able to trace the code to parts where it is printing out the ">>> " prompt, but how it was handling not printing out the prompt when started as a background process was beyond me. And I know that obviously you would never start an input/output interactive program in the background as that goes against intended functionality and common sense, but I am more interested in the concepts behind it like if this was implemented with signal handling and/or if this is some more advanced input/output stream buffering or some other Unix concept that I am not familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing your version of `bc` does is call the `tcsetattr` function. This function, when called from a background process, causes the `SIGTTOU` signal to be sent to the process, which by default causes the process to stop.

Any program that manipulates terminal attributes (vim, bash, anything that uses `readline` or `curses`, ...) will probably behave exactly the same way.